# distribuir valor entre varios registros en base a otro valor SQL

Tags: sql, tsql, transact-sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta sencilla

```
SELECT 
 Number
,Total
,InteresRef
,NumeroPago
FROM tabla 
WHERE Number = '00700248'
```

me arroja el siguiente resultado

```
  Number        Total       InteresRef  NumeroPago
00700248      20570.66        748.30        1
00700248      20570.66        748.30        2
00700248      20570.66        748.30        3
00700248      20570.66        748.30        4
00700248      20570.66        748.30        5
00700248      20570.66        748.30        6
00700248      20570.66        748.30        7
00700248      20570.66        748.30        8
00700248      20570.66        748.30        9
00700248      20570.66        748.30        10
00700248      20570.66        748.30        11
00700248      20570.66        748.30        12
00700248      20570.66        748.30        13
00700248      20570.66        748.30        14
00700248      20570.66        748.30        15
00700248      20570.66        748.30        16
00700248      20570.66        748.30        17
00700248      20570.66        748.30        18
00700248      20570.66        748.30        19
00700248      20570.66        748.30        20
00700248      20570.66        748.30        21
00700248      20570.66        748.30        22
00700248      20570.66        748.30        23
00700248      20570.66        748.30        24
00700248      20570.66        748.30        25
00700248      20570.66        748.30        26
00700248      20570.66        748.30        27
00700248      20570.66        748.30        28
00700248      20570.66        748.30        29
00700248      20570.66        748.30        30
00700248      20570.66        748.30        31
00700248      20570.66        748.30        32
00700248      20570.66        748.30        33
00700248      20570.66        748.30        34
00700248      20570.66        748.30        35
00700248      20570.66        748.30        36
00700248      20570.66        748.31        37
00700248      20570.66        748.30        38
00700248      20570.66        748.31        39
00700248      20570.66        748.30        40
00700248      20570.66        748.31        41
00700248      20570.66        748.30        42
00700248      20570.66        748.31        43
00700248      20570.66        748.30        44
00700248      20570.66        748.31        45
00700248      20570.66        748.30        46
00700248      20570.66        748.31        47
00700248      20570.66        748.30        48
00700248      20570.66        748.31        49
00700248      20570.66        748.30        50
00700248      20570.66        748.31        51
00700248      20570.66        748.30        52
00700248      20570.66        748.31        53
00700248      20570.66        748.30        54
00700248      20570.66        748.31        55
00700248      20570.66        748.30        56
00700248      20570.66        748.31        57
00700248      20570.66        748.30        58
00700248      20570.66        748.31        59
00700248      20570.66        748.30        60
00700248      20570.66        748.31        61
00700248      20570.66        748.30        62
00700248      20570.66        748.31        63
00700248      20570.66        748.30        64
00700248      20570.66        748.31        65
00700248      20570.66        748.30        66
00700248      20570.66        748.31        67
00700248      20570.66        748.30        68
00700248      20570.66        748.31        69
00700248      20570.66        748.30        70
00700248      20570.66        748.31        71
00700248      20570.66        748.30        72
00700248      20570.66        748.31        73
00700248      20570.66        748.30        74
00700248      20570.66        748.31        75
00700248      20570.66        748.30        76
00700248      20570.66        748.31        77
00700248      20570.66        748.30        78
00700248      20570.66        748.31        79
00700248      20570.66        748.30        80
00700248      20570.66        748.31        81
00700248      20570.66        748.30        82
00700248      20570.66        748.31        83
00700248      20570.66        748.30        84
00700248      20570.66        748.31        85
00700248      20570.66        748.30        86
00700248      20570.66        748.31        87
00700248      20570.66        748.30        88
00700248      20570.66        748.31        89
00700248      20570.66        748.30        90
00700248      20570.66        748.31        91
00700248      20570.66        748.30        92
00700248      20570.66        748.31        93
00700248      20570.66        748.30        94
00700248      20570.66        748.31        95
00700248      20570.66        748.30        96
```

lo que quiero es una nueva columna que me distribuya el campo Total entre los 96 registros pero en base al campo InteresRef

Este es el resultado que espero

```
Number        Total  InteresRef  NumeroPago NuevoCampo
00700248    20,570.66   748.3      1          748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      2          748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      3          748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      4          748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      5          748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      6          748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      7          748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      8          748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      9          748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      10         748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      11         748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      12         748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      13         748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      14         748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      15         748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      16         748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      17         748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      18         748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      19         748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      20         748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      21         748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      22         748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      23         748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      24         748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      25         748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      26         748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      27         748.3
00700248    20570.66    748.3      28         366.56 
00700248    20570.66    748.3      29   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      30   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      31   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      32   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      33   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      34   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      35   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      36   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     37   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      38   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     39   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      40   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     41   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      42   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     43   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      44   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     45   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      46   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     47   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      48   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     49   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      50   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     51   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      52   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     53   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      54   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     55   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      56   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     57   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      58   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     59   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      60   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     61   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      62   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     63   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      64   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     65   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      66   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     67   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      68   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     69   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      70   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     71   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      72   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     73   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      74   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     75   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      76   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     77   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      78   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     79   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      80   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     81   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      82   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     83   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      84   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     85   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      86   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     87   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      88   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     89   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      90   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     91   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      92   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     93   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      94   
00700248    20570.66    748.31     95   
00700248    20570.66    748.3      96
```

Como puedo realizar esto?

Comment: No entendi bien la pregunta, pero que tal si pruebas despues de ,InteresRef
,NumeroPago, InteresRef as NuevaColumna

Comment: podrias ser mas claro, cual seria la condicion para esta nueva columna? porque la diferencia es 1 columna nueva y el primer registro con coma!

Comment: Por ejemplo, el total es de 20570.66, quiero distribuir ese valor entre los 96 registros  en base al campo InteresRef, por ejemplo en el primer registro el nuevo campo debe de tener el mismo valor del InteresRef  pero ese valor se lo voy restando a los 20570.66, y así registro por registro, al llegar al registro 27 como le va restando valor por valor ya solo quedan 366.56 que es distinto de 748.3, y por eso en la cuota 28 le coloque 366.56 que es lo restante para que sumando toda esa columna NuevoCampo sean iguales a los 20570.66

Comment: no tiene ningun sentido hacer esto en la base de datos.. pero si lo queres hacer asi, usa una funcion ventana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un `CASE` lo puedes hacer

```
SELECT Number,
      total,
      InteresRef,
      NumeroPago,
      CASE
            WHEN total - InteresRef*NumeroPago <= InteresRef and total - InteresRef*NumeroPago >=0  THEN  total - InteresRef*NumeroPago 
            WHEN total - InteresRef*NumeroPago < InteresRef THEN null
            ELSE InteresRef
          END AS NuevoCampo
  FROM tabla
```

donde tienes esta formula `total - InteresRef*NumeroPago` que te arroja cuanto resta después de cada pago

Entonces,

**Primera condición:**

`WHEN total - InteresRef*NumeroPago <= InteresRef and total - InteresRef*NumeroPago >=0  THEN  total - InteresRef*NumeroPago`

Se produce cuando lo que resta es menor o igual a `InteresRef` y mayor o igual a cero. En el ejemplo seria el pago n°27

Para este caso, devolvemos la diferencia (el resto)

**Segunda condición:**

`WHEN total - InteresRef*NumeroPago < 0 THEN null`

Sí la diferencia es menor a cero, devolvemos null (o podría ser cero)

Esto en el ejemplo son desde el pago 28 en adelante

**En cualquier otro caso**

Devolvemos `InteresRef`

Comment: Una consulta, en el caso de que yo quisiera que a partir del segundo registro comience a restar, ¿Como seria?

Answer (score 0):

Si alguna ves a alguien le funciona esta opción, les comparto otra solución que he realizado usando OVER

```
 SELECT 
 Number
,Total
,InteresRef
,NumeroPago
,,IIF((CASE
           WHEN Total - SUM(InteresRef) OVER(ORDER BY FechaPago, Number) >= InteresRef THEN InteresRef
           WHEN Total - SUM(InteresRef) OVER(ORDER BY FechaPago, Number) < InteresRef THEN Total - SUM(InteresRef) OVER(ORDER BY FechaPago, Number)
           END) <0 , 0, (CASE
                              WHEN Total - SUM(InteresRef) OVER(ORDER BY FechaPago, Number) >= InteresRef THEN InteresRef
                              WHEN Total - SUM(InteresRef) OVER(ORDER BY FechaPago, Number) < InteresRef THEN Total - SUM(InteresRef) OVER(ORDER BY FechaPago, Number)
                              END)) AS NuevoCampo


FROM tabla 
WHERE Number = '00700248'igo aquí
```

Comment: Tenés un par de _typos_ en tu consulta. No olvides además explicar el funcionamiento de la misma.

Comment: Es buena opción, pero al ya tener el número de pago no es necesario el procesamiento adicional de las funciones de ventana.